# how to use tabController in riverpod

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I would like to manage TabController state in riverpod.

But error of `Undefined name 'vsync'` will happen

```
final recentWatchScreenTabStateTestProvider = StateProvider((ref) => TabController(
    length: 3, 
    vsync: vsync, // error here
));
```

How to fix this?

or I can't manage TabController state in riverpod?

If use StatefullWidget, I can use TabController.

But, I want to use TabController in another Widget.

Answer (score 0):

To get `vsync` you have to use the mixin [SingleTickerProviderStateMixin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleTickerProviderStateMixin-mixin.html). Here is a small example:

```dart
class MyTabbedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTabbedPage({ super.key });

  @override
  State<MyTabbedPage> createState() => _MyTabbedPageState();
}

class _MyTabbedPageState extends State<MyTabbedPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final recentWatchScreenTabStateTestProvider = StateProvider((ref) => TabController(
      length: 3, 
      vsync: this,
    ));
  }
}
```

If you need more info check out [TabController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabController-class.html).

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea. but, i can't call recentWatchScreenTabStateTestProvider in another widget

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a slightly different way. Let each widget that needs a `TabController` create one based on parameters from other providers:

```dart
/// "parameter" provider. Track wherever you need to.
final lengthProvider = Provider<int>((ref) {
  return 3;
});

class MyTabbedPage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const MyTabbedPage({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<MyTabbedPage> createState() => _MyTabbedPageState();
}

class _MyTabbedPageState extends ConsumerState<MyTabbedPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AutoDisposeProvider<TabController> recentWatchScreenTabStateTestProvider;

  @override
  void initState() {
    recentWatchScreenTabStateTestProvider = Provider.autoDispose(
      (ref) => TabController(
        length: ref.watch(lengthProvider),
        vsync: this,
      ),
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tabCtrl = ref.watch(recentWatchScreenTabStateTestProvider);
    return TabBarView(
      controller: tabCtrl,
      children: [],
    );
  }
}
```

That way, in another widget where you need a `TabController` you can again create based on the `lengthProvider` (and others you define).

But, for good, in this case it is worth abandoning the use of a provider for `TabController` and organizing it all through the usual `StatefulWidget` and overridden `initState` and `dispose` methods. And to receive parameters in `initState` through `ref.read(lengthProvider)`. Each widget will have its own tab controller

Comment: Thanks for detail explanation.

In your example, if i use animateTo function of **tabCtrl**  in another widget, how can I use that?

Comment: In the other widget you must create a new `tabCtrl` based on the values of the other providers. And then, for example, in the callback call `tabCtrl.animateTo(5);` or `ref.read(...estProvider).animateTo(5);`

Answer (score 0):

Using [flutter_hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks) you can simply do as follows

```
class AnnouncementTabBarWidget extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const AnnouncementTabBarWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final tabController = useTabController(initialLength: 2);

    AsyncValue<AnnouncementsResponseData> announcementsList =
        ref.watch(announcementModelFutureProvider);

    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            left: kDefaultMiddlePadding,
            right: kDefaultMiddlePadding,
          ),
          child: TabBar(
            controller: tabController,
            tabs: const [
              Tab(
                text: "Güncel Duyurular",
              ),
              Tab(
                text: "Geçmiş Duyurular",
              ),
            ],
            labelColor: Colors.black,
            unselectedLabelColor: kDisabledColor,
            labelStyle: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .titleMedium!
                .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            onTap: (value) {
              /*  ref.read(calendarNotifierProvider("main").notifier).changePickupDate(null); */
            },
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: announcementsList.when(
          data: (data) {
            return TabBarView(
              controller: tabController,
              children: [
                AnnouncementCurrentWidget(
                    newAnnouncement: data.newAnnouncements),
                AnnouncementOldWidget(oldAnnouncement: data.oldAnnouncements),
              ],
            );
          },
          error: (error, stackTrace) {
            return generalErrorHandler(context);
          },
          loading: () {
            return const GlobalIndicatorWidget();
          },
        )),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```